# What does "child" mean in Chrome Devtools?

Tags: javascript, debugging, backbone.js, google-chrome-devtools, watch

Since the first time I saw this "child" note, I can't understand: what does that mean?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the "type" of the object that is somehow derived by the console API. Often it seems to be the name of the constructor function that created the object. Example:

[image]

The console API and output are not standardized, so environments can do whatever they want. It's not a feature of JavaScript and therefore not really relevant for writing your code.

I can only imagine the purpose is that you can more quickly recognize the "type" of the object when inspecting an object.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case with Backbone, because it doesn't have a constructor function in its code named `child`.

Comment: There might be other heuristics the console uses to determine the type. This is just one of them. Again, the behavior is not standardized and might differ between environments.

Comment: There actually is a constructor function named `child` in backbone.js - it's inside [`extend` method](http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js), which is used to produce the objects.

Comment: [here's the child you're looking for](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/4a02b5fc3d9759ed8d3180b37cd982c8b30f8696/backbone.js#L1983)

Comment: Yes, you guys are right. It's not that the function is actually named `child`, it's just saved in a variable with that name (and so `typeof` returns `"object"`). Nevertheless, Devtools uses that name :) Fascinating.

Comment: @MikhailBatcer: `typeof` has nothing to do with that. That's why I put "type" in parenthesis. It's a purely informational/presentational feature of the browser console. Regarding the function name however, if the result of an anonymous function expression is assigned to a variable, then the name of the variable becomes the name of the function: `var foo = function(){}; console.log(foo.name);`. That is standardized.